# Calculate the client-server UTC offset using EPOC value javascript

Tags: javascript, utc

We are trying to calculate the client-server time offset by using EPOC value sent from backend API, when doing that I am running into an issue in local browser/client side.

when i get EPOC from backend API I.e. serverEpocValue = 1653107370620 and trying to compare it with the local epoc value the difference is not 6 hours as I expected, it's around few milliseconds difference, why is epoc value close to local time instead of the server time?

```
const serverdate = new Date(1653107370620)
```

serverDate =
Sat May 21 2022 09:59:30 GMT+0530 (locale browser date and time)

How do we get the server UTC time using epoc to calculate the offset in the client side?

Comment: What does "EPOC" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The time through facilities `Date.now()` will always be in milliseconds from Jan 1 1970 UTC and does not consider timezones.  If you need to get the timezone offset you should use something like `Date.getTimezoneOffset`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

which will return the offset in minutes.